# Changing string patterns to elements using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm converting an embedded text pattern to an element.

Everything I seem to do add `&lt;hit&gt;` rather than `<hit>`.

Here is my input...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <lst>
      <lst id="7c5d14cd1225d94ff8dd9cf06eb67f05">
         <arr name="note">
            <str>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tellus risus,
iaculis id convallis sagittis, convallis in purus. Suspendisse imperdiet, enim
aliquam varius gravida, eros sapien mattis metus, vel suscipit lacus lacus eget
sem. Nulla ullamcorper enim quis dolor pellentesque consectetur quis quis eros.
Pellentesque et urna @@pre@@corn@@post@@, vel gravida urna. Nulla facilisi. Sed condimentum
purus non magna tristique molestie. Aliquam vulputate lobortis cursus. Morbi
tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Praesent in sapien diam. Aliquam bibendum elit ut
massa tristique tincidunt eu vel nisl. Aenean @@pre@@corn@@post@@ nulla id urna laoreet tempus.
Etiam ultricies lacus a arcu ornare iaculis. In eget tempus nisi.
        </str>
         </arr>
      </lst>
      <lst id="0e18352acb70ff7c4441dfd201dd7cd1">
         <arr name="note">
            <str>
Proin vitae eleifend enim. Nullam quis mauris ipsum. Proin sem dolor, placerat
nec ornare et, pulvinar a arcu. Cras varius venenatis sapien, eu sagittis sem
laoreet nec. Sed congue elit et magna tincidunt in ultrices quam rhoncus.
Maecenas ullamcorper pellentesque lobortis. Nunc blandit semper neque, vel
rhoncus tortor lacinia nec. Praesent sed feugiat @@pre@@corn@@post@@. Integer vel arcu leo,
sit amet volutpat diam. Cras posuere tristique est, ut tristique nibh
sollicitudin et. Pellentesque vitae justo sapien, non imperdiet velit.
        </str>
         </arr>
      </lst>
   </lst>
</response>
```

My result should be...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <lst>
      <lst id="7c5d14cd1225d94ff8dd9cf06eb67f05">
         <arr name="note">
            <str>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus tellus risus,
iaculis id convallis sagittis, convallis in purus. Suspendisse imperdiet, enim
aliquam varius gravida, eros sapien mattis metus, vel suscipit lacus lacus eget
sem. Nulla ullamcorper enim quis dolor pellentesque consectetur quis quis eros.
Pellentesque et urna <hit>corn</hit>, vel gravida urna. Nulla facilisi. Sed condimentum
purus non magna tristique molestie. Aliquam vulputate lobortis cursus. Morbi
tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Praesent in sapien diam. Aliquam bibendum elit ut
massa tristique tincidunt eu vel nisl. Aenean <hit>corn</hit> nulla id urna laoreet tempus.
Etiam ultricies lacus a arcu ornare iaculis. In eget tempus nisi.
        </str>
         </arr>
      </lst>
      <lst id="0e18352acb70ff7c4441dfd201dd7cd1">
         <arr name="note">
            <str>
Proin vitae eleifend enim. Nullam quis mauris ipsum. Proin sem dolor, placerat
nec ornare et, pulvinar a arcu. Cras varius venenatis sapien, eu sagittis sem
laoreet nec. Sed congue elit et magna tincidunt in ultrices quam rhoncus.
Maecenas ullamcorper pellentesque lobortis. Nunc blandit semper neque, vel
rhoncus tortor lacinia nec. Praesent sed feugiat <hit>corn</hit>. Integer vel arcu leo,
sit amet volutpat diam. Cras posuere tristique est, ut tristique nibh
sollicitudin et. Pellentesque vitae justo sapien, non imperdiet velit.
        </str>
         </arr>
      </lst>
   </lst>
</response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well basically you would use `analyze-string` e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="arr/str">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="@@pre@@(.+)@@post@@">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <hit>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        </hit>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

[edit] I have changed the regular expression a bit to simply collect anything that is not a `@` character, and here is a full stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="arr/str">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="@@pre@@([^@]+)@@post@@">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <hit>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        </hit>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way you should get a better result if there are several patterns in one line. If it still does not work as you want then please post more detailed input data.

Comment: That does not work for the case where there is more than one hit in a single line.

Comment: I have edited the code to address the problem you have raised.

Comment: One last thing. In my real use case, one instance of the content is "@@pre@@Corn@@post@@", but the output lowers the case to "<hit>corn</hit>".  Is that solvable as well?

Comment: I can't see why that would happen, for any match of the regular expression pattern `@@pre@@([^@]+)@@post@@` the code simply outputs what has been collected by `([^@]+)` so `Corn` should be output as `Corn`. Which XSLT 2.0 processor are you using? I tested with Saxon 9.5 and the pattern `Cras @@pre@@Corn@@post@@ posuere` is transformed into `Cras <hit>Corn</hit> posuere`.